# How to download google books online in android?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm creating an android application where in i need to find the books on google and download them in my sdcard for reading those books.

I searched for this online but did not get any clue of how to download the book that i have searched for. Can anybody please give me some links or sample on how to do it.

https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started

I have seen this site but it does not describe how to dowload the book.

Comment: First you should cross check that its not against T&C of the book's publisher

Comment: I just want to know do we have to create a server for maintaining all this or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google books is an API that can be used to retrieve the metadata of a book, not the book's content. You can see book's title, author ISBN etc, though.

You need to find some other API for retrieving the content, though I doubt there is suitable one in the general case, because books are usually paid for, you know.

Comment: So do i have to maintain a server in order to download the books?

Comment: @devika: I don't know where you will find the book contents. It is not going to be in the Google Boooks API. If there is no public API, then you will have to maintain your own server. For the metadata, however Google Books is sufficient and you need not maintain your server.

Comment: But i need to download the book in form of epub or pdf

Comment: @devika I am not aware of any such public API. Google books will not help.

Answer (score 0):

in this post: [How to download a Document from ipaper swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170771/how-to-download-a-document-from-ipaper-swf/38198147#38198147) 
I answered how to download online books in a pc.
for android you should search for capturing traffic solution to track how your application works (like the network capturing in pc browsers).
the remaining should be the same